# Site editor vs. site visitor permissions

Tags: permissions, active-directory, groups

We have a single site collection on SharePoint 2010 with some 30 departmental web sites. Each site has its own editors group, and they're set to AD groups. Editors for one department can't edit another department's web site.

We use a single group "Intranet Visitors" to grant read access to the site collection to everyone on the AD group "IntranetUsers". We've noticed that for the users who aren't in this group but are in the Editor group for a site, they still can't access the site.

I thought editors would have read access. Here are the permissions set for the Editors:

List Permissions

- Add Items
- Edit Items
- Delete Items
- View Items
- Open Items
- View Versions

Site Permissions

- View Pages
- Open

What are we missing from the Editor permission level that prevents users from being able to view the sites? Thanks.
Then we have Editor groups on the web sites with the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the editors group have read permissions on the sites where they are not editors?  Is everyone in the organization in the IntranetUsers group?

You have to make sure that even though a user might be an editor of site A, they are either granted read access by the blanket AD group to site B or if they were excluded from that group because they're an editor, that editor group B has been given read access to site A.